# AJAX request issues with Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a checkbox that sends an AJAX request everytime the state of the checkbox is changed (checked/unchecked). I was testing everything in Chrome, and it all works fine.

However, it is when I use Firefox or IE, the AJAX request does not change the value in the SQL server. I'm a little confused of why it's not working, and I'm fairly new to JS and JQuery, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the function where I use AJAX to call a PHP page to change the checkbox value.

```
        //This function handles the clicking of checkboxes in the list
        //It sends an ajax POST message to a separate php file that handles the database updating
        function checkboxClicked(checkboxType, ticketNumber){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'updateCheckbox.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: 'true',
                data: {checkboxType: checkboxType, ticketNumber: ticketNumber},

                success: function(result, status){
                    if (status == "success"){
                        console.log("Status: " + status + ", Result: " + result);
                    }
                }
            });

            if(checkboxType == "Received"){
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
```

Here is the line in PHP where it shows the checkbox status:

```
<?php
                        //This loop populates the ticket display using the records in the database
                        while($recordSet->EOF == false){
                            $ticketNumber = $recordSet->Fields['TicketNumber'];
                            $dateSubmitted = $recordSet->Fields['DateSubmitted'];
                            $department = $recordSet->Fields['Department'];
                            $courseNo = $recordSet->Fields['CourseNumber'];
                            $instructorName = $recordSet->Fields['InstructorName'];
                            $received = ($recordSet->Fields['Received']) ? "checked" : "unchecked";
                            $sendReminder = ($recordSet->Fields['SendReminder']) ? "checked" : "unchecked";
                            $email = $recordSet->Fields['Email'];
                            $CC = $recordSet->Fields['CC'];


                            $strHTML  = "<tr><td>$dateSubmitted</td>\n";
                            $strHTML .= "<td>$department</td>\n";
                            $strHTML .= "<td>$courseNo</td>\n";
                            $strHTML .= "<td style='word-break: break-all'>$instructorName</td>\n";
                            $strHTML .= "<td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' id='received' ".$received." class='receivedCheckbox' onclick='checkboxClicked(\"Received\", ".$ticketNumber.")'/></td>\n";
                            $strHTML .= "<td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' id='sendReminder' ".$sendReminder." class='sendReminderCheckbox' onchange='checkboxClicked(\"SendReminder\", ".$ticketNumber.")' data-email='".$email."'/></td>\n";
                            $strHTML .= "<td style='word-break: break-all;' align='center'> <a id='checkReceived' href='#' onClick='checkReceived(\"$received\", \"$email\")'>".$email."</a></td>";
                            $strHTML .= "<td align='center'> <button onclick=\"window.open('urlhere', '_self')\">Edit</button>\n";
                            $strHTML .= "<td align='center'> <button onclick=\"window.open('urlhere')\">Print</button> </td>\n";
                            $strHTML .= "</tr>\n";

                            echo $strHTML;
                            $recordSet->MoveNext;
                        }
                    ?>
```

If you guys need more information, just let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: check console for any error

Comment: Checked console, no error.

Comment: How are you triggering the checkboxClicked function?

Comment: By reloading the page, you cancel current running request. How it is handled across browser can be different. So at least try: `$.ajax({...}).always(function(){if(checkboxType == "Received"){
                window.location.reload();
            }});`. FYI, `async: 'true',` should be `async: true,` or just omit it BUT that's not relative to your issue

Comment: onclick event for the checkbox.

Comment: Hi, can you give us more detail, like console or network info ?

Comment: is there any error being generated in console while page is being loaded or on click event?

Comment: Hey A. Wolff, I tried your method, but it only works for the first few changes. Console does not give any error messages, and I send the request to a SQL database where I store true/false if the checkbox is checked or not,

Comment: @AndyWong `but it only works for the first few changes` What does mean??? And check network tab in console, isn't ajax request just aborted?

Comment: So I check the checkbox, it works the first time. But if I check/uncheck other checkboxes in succession, it does not work.

Comment: @AndyWong Without seeing what you are doing, we can only guessing you are doing something wrong. Describe what is your expected behaviour compares to what you get. And btw, why are you reloading the page???

Comment: jQuery returned "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead." I'm reloading the page to re-populate PHP variables. The value of the checkbox is also stored in a PHP variable, which I use in other functions as well.

Comment: What I want it to do: when i click the checkbox, it sends the change to the SQL server, and show on the webpage that the checkbox state has been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should try :

```
 $received = ($recordSet->Fields['Received']) ? "checked='checked' " : "checked='' ";
 $sendReminder = ($recordSet->Fields['SendReminder']) ? "checked='checked' " : "checked='' ";
```